# A topological space is regular if..

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and let $x \in X$ and let $A$ be a nonempty closed subset of $X$ that does not contain $x$.  If there exists a continuous mapping from $X$ into the real closed interval $[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=\{0\}$ and $f[A]=\{1\}$ then $(X, \tau)$ is regular.

I have no idea how to prove this, I was thinking letting $U$ be the set of all $x$ such that $f(x)=\{1\}$. Clearly $A \subseteq U$ and since $f$ is contiuous we get that $f^{-1}(\{1\})=U$ is open.  The problem is if $U=A$ then that means $A$ is open which cannot happen.  Any suggestions/help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A\subseteq f^{-1}(1/2,3/2)$ and $f^{-1}(1/2,3/2)$ is open that does not contain $x$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{2}$ we chosen arbitrarily correct? Basically any $2$ numbers that include $1$ and not $0$?

Comment: Yes, any pair that contains $1$ but no $0$ will do.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The space is regular if we can do this for every such pair $A$ and $x \notin A$, yes. When such functions always exist the space is called a "Tychonoff space".

You need some room between $0$ and $1$ to get separating open sets by inverse images of open sets in the reals.

Use $U = f^{-1}[(r, 1+r)]$ around $A$ for some $1> r>0$ and $V = f^{-1}[(-r,r)]$ for $x$, say.